# Internet explorer - focus event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have input fields set to readonly, and when they gain focus I remove the readonly attribute to prevent the autofill behavior, but it works on all browsers except IE.

`jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/rbx0vgcs/

I tried timeouts, I tried native JS, nothing seems to work, any suggestions?

Comment: It's working fine on IE too

Comment: @CME64 On IE the field remains uneditable even on focus

Comment: in fact what you are doing is funny because you are blocking the field and still want it to be editable. don't use readonly because some browsers may run different logic like blocking the focus of the field by the readonly which you change after the focus. try another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<input autocomplete="new-password" />`

[Courtesy of MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code in IE. focus works but I doesn't remove attribute from DOM.

try following code :

```js
$('input').on('focus', function(){
  console.log(this.attributes.length);
  $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
  console.log(this.attributes.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly>
```

As you can see, before removing the readonly, attributes.length is 1 and after it will be 0.

It works in IE also.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to blur and re-focus the input field after it has been made editable.